# "text-indent" stopt working after adding an href

Tags: html, css, text-indent

I'm really new to CSS and I'm trying to hide some text with with the "text-indent" method but after adding an `<a>` -tag it just wouldn't work anymore.

I now got my img and the the text
with `#english{}` i get no text but the `<a>` doesn't work.

stuff like text-transform works just fine so I think I'm targeting the right part.
I tried to `text-align: none;` before the `text-indent:`.

```css
nav ul {
  text-align: center;
}

nav li {
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: large;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  width: 160px;
}

nav li ul {
  display: inline-flex;
  width: 100px;
}

#english a {
  background-image: url('images/languages/english.png');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  text-indent: -9999999px;
}

#german a {
  background-image: url('images/languages/german.png');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  text-indent: -9999999px;
}

#chinese a {
  background-image: url('images/languages/chinese.png');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  text-indent: -9999999px;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li>Home</li>
    <li>Biografie</li>
    <li>Termine</li>
    <li>Medien</li>
    <li>Kontakt</li>
    <li>
      <ul>
        <li id="english"><a href="en/home.html">english</a></li>
        <li id="german"><a href="deutsch.html">german</a></li>
        <li id="chinese"><a href="chinesisch.html">chinese</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>

  </ul>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-indent

> The text-indent CSS property sets the length of empty space (indentation) that is put before lines of text in a block.
>
> Horizontal spacing is with respect to the left (or right, for right-to-left layout) edge of the containing block-level element's content box.

so you need a block-level element

```css
nav ul {
  text-align: center;
}

nav li {
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: large;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  width: 160px;
}

nav li ul {
  display: inline-flex;
  width: 100px;
}

nav li ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  text-indent: -9999999px;
}

#english a {
  background-image: url('images/languages/english.png');
}

#german a {
  background-image: url('images/languages/german.png');
}

#chinese a {
  background-image: url('images/languages/chinese.png');
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li>Home</li>
    <li>Biografie</li>
    <li>Termine</li>
    <li>Medien</li>
    <li>Kontakt</li>
    <li>
      <ul>
        <li id="english"><a href="en/home.html">english</a></li>
        <li id="german"><a href="deutsch.html">german</a></li>
        <li id="chinese"><a href="chinesisch.html">chinese</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>

  </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: yeah but that also moves my images... 

Comment: it moves all the list to -999...px

Comment: So what do you actually want?

Comment: I'm trying to make just the text go sideways not the images, to make a nav where you can click on a flag to change the language

Comment: Why not just `<ul><li><a href="en/home.html"><img src="images/languages/english.png" title="English"/></a></li>....`